# Deploying Oracle Instant Client alongside existing Oracle installations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oracle, odp.net

I have developed a new application that uses Entity Framework to access an Oracle database. This is working as expected locally, using the latest version of ODP.NET. I am now trying to deploy this application on a production server running many other legacy applications. Ideally I would like my new application to make use of its own ODP.NET / Oracle dlls and not have to change the existing Oracle install on the prod server.

I followed this guide:

http://jeremybranham.wordpress.com/2011/04/25/oracle-instant-client-with-odp-net/

Which seems to have had some success based on the comments.

However, I get the following exception when attempting to create the entities object:

**Outer Exception**

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

**Inner Exception**

```
The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory' threw an exception.
at System.RuntimeFieldHandle.GetValue(RtFieldInfo field, Object instance, RuntimeType fieldType, RuntimeType declaringType, Boolean& domainInitialized)
at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.InternalGetValue(Object obj, Boolean doVisibilityCheck, Boolean doCheckConsistency)
at System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo.GetValue(Object obj)
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(DataRow providerRow)
at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String providerInvariantName)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String providerString)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String connectionString)
at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString, String defaultContainerName)
at MyAppMVC.Models.DataModels.STSProcedureEntities..ctor()
at MyAppMVC.Services.MyService.GetPersons(String lastName)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question here. We ultimately installed a second version of Oracle, using the default settings which put the new version into a client_2 folder.

- D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client (old version)
- D:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_2 (new version)

The only additional install step was dropping in the previous TNSNAMES.ORA file into the new client_2. This file is located in client\network\admin using the file path above.

Because all of our applications were set to specifically seek out their correct Oracle versions (SpecificVersion=true) everything mostly worked without modification. For those that did not we had to drop in the older version of Oracle.DataAccess.dll (from client, not client_2) into that application's bin folder.

Answer (score 2):

Although you appear to have resolved your problem by installing an additional client you could possible have added the following config in you app / web.config file.

```
  <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" />
      <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET"
           type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, 
           PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
```

And dropped the binaries in your local bin folder.